# Getting Values From Database Table and Use it to Define Constants

Tags: php, constants

I have a small table of 4 columns and 1 row of data in it. The table is such that it cannot hold more than 1 row. What might be the code to define column names as constants and data from table as the constants' value?

[1st Edit]
I could have defined the constants directly, but the table needs to be updated so as the constants. I don't want to use them through session variables cause other tables' rows are affected by this particular table's column values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try array:

```
$data = array(
'column1' => 'value1',
'column2' => 'value2',
'column3' => 'value3',
'column4' => 'value4'
);
```

In this case you will have table view at array:

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4
value1  | value2  | value3  | value4
```

Also i't possible to create ini file:

```
column1 = value1
column2 = value2
column3 = value3
column4 = value4
```

And use php function `parse_ini_file`.

Or you can use contants:

```
define("column1","value1");
define("column2","value2");
define("column3","value3");
define("column4","value4");
```

Or it's possible to create database and store this values in it.

So, I would say. You should be more specific and tell us why do you need this :)

Answer (score 0):

How about put those data in a .php file and include that php in every file, it can save your time implementing query code to obtain those data:

```
define("COLUMN1_DATA","your data");
define("COLUMN2_DATA","your data2");
define("COLUMN3_DATA","your data3");
define("COLUMN4_DATA","your data4");
```

Comment: Unless you have any other important reasons that you need to put them in a table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a `config.php` file to store the constants

and in your `config.php` file code looks like

```
$config['column1']='value1';
$config['column2']='value2';
$config['column3']='value3';
$config['column4']='value4';
```

in the other pages u can include the `config.php`  by

```
require_once 'config.php'
```